# powershell | Copy-Item from a CSV list of File Names, Log in that same CSV

Tags: powershell, logging

Good Day Powershell Users

I have a simple script that reads a CSV with a single column filename list (first line **header** called **name**, list names with no extension) and then search for them in a source path, after that it copies those files to another destination path.

CSV Example

```
Name
FV_2017_12_161207
FV_2017_12_161208
FV_2017_12_161209
FV_2017_12_161210
.
.
.
```

It works fine but for the sake of keeping a record in case a file doesn't exists i added a Start-Transcript/Stop-Transcript with a TXT file.

This is my code:

```
$source = "\\192.168.1.3\anexos\"
$endpath = ".\seleccion\"
$LogFile = "errorlog.txt"
Start-Transcript -path $LogFile -append
Import-Csv list.csv | ForEach-Object {
    Copy-Item $source$($_.name).pdf $endpath
}
Stop-Transcript
```

It does the Job but i want to go a little further.

Is there a way to write in the same CSV list for each line if the file was successfully copied or not?

CSV Example

```
Name               Copy
FV_2017_12_161207  Ok
FV_2017_12_161208  Fail
FV_2017_12_161209  Fail
FV_2017_12_161211  Ok
FV_2017_12_161212  Ok
FV_2017_12_161213  Ok
.
.
.
```

Any help and tips to improve my humble code is greatly appreciated, thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will be super easy!  All we really need to do is to add a check to see if a file exists before you try to copy it, I'd do that with `Test-Path` here.

```
Import-Csv list.csv | ForEach-Object {
    if (Test-Path $_.Name){
        #FileExists
        Copy-Item $source$($_.name).pdf $endpath
    }
}
```

Then, we'll create a PSObject to track that we copied the file.

```
ForEach-Object {
    if (Test-Path $_.Name){
        #file exists
        Copy-Item $source$($_.name).pdf $endpath
        [pscustomobject]@{FileName=$_.Name;Copied=$true}
        }
}
```

The final step is to add an `else{}` script block, to create an object if we fail to copy the file.

```
 ForEach-Object {
    if (Test-Path $_.Name){
        #file exists
        Copy-Item $source$($_.name).pdf $endpath
        [pscustomobject]@{FileName=$_.Name;Copied=$true}
        }
    else{
        #no
        [pscustomobject]@{FileName=$_.Name;Copied=$false}
        }

}
```

And here's what it looks like in action.

```
FileName        Copied
--------        ------
v.vbs             True
WorkingHinv.mp4   True
DoesntExist.Not  False
test.xlsx         True
```

You could also store the results in an array, and then display the array at the end then store as a CSV for record keeping.

Just add `$Array=@()` at the start of your code, and then add `$array+=` before each `[pscustomobj]...` line.  You can then save it by running

```
$array | Export-CSV .\CopyLog.Csv
```

Comment: Excellent, i have no complaints about making a second CSV file, 
It works like a charm, with a little tweaking

Comment: Just a note, you will not need to use Transcription with this approach either.  Just run the script and look at the output .CSV file.